# Annotation processing order - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, android, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

**What I have:**

1. I have written an annotation processor `@ViewModel` which generates classes `ViewModel_<annotated class name>`.
2. I have written another annotation processor `@Retainable` which generates builders for fields annotated with `@Retainable`.

My implementation is based on this article:

http://blog.stablekernel.com/the-10-step-guide-to-annotation-processing-in-android-studio

but I have two annotation processors.

**My problem:**

If I annotate field of type `ViewModel_<annotated class name>` with my `@Retainable` annotation.

```
...
@Retainable
ViewModel_<annotated class name> viewModelGenerated;
...
```

the compiler complains:

> Error:(33, 15) error: cannot find symbol class ViewModel_<annotated class name>

but,

If I annotate this field with daggers `@Inject` instead of my `@Retainable` everything is compiling.

**Question:**

What is the difference between my annotation and daggers?
What can I do to make it work?

Comment: It is hard to diagnose your issues, since you don't have a self-contained sample of problem, haven't posted any relevant code, and the error descriptions are pretty much useless. But note, that linked article is *abhorrent* as a guideline for writing annotation processors. You should understand the mechanics of multi-round compilation and the purpose of  `ErrorType` before trying to do the things you are trying to do (using not-yet-existing types in code & running multiple  inter-dependant annotation processors).

Comment: Thank you for yor answer. I will try to update my question with minimum sample which provides the same error. What would you recommend as good guideline for writing annotation processors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadoc of the `Processor` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html).

> Annotation processing happens in a sequence of rounds. On each round, a processor may be asked to process a subset of the annotations found on the source and class files produced by a prior round. The inputs to the first round of processing are the initial inputs to a run of the tool; these initial inputs can be regarded as the output of a virtual zeroth round of processing.

`Processor.process` is called once for each round. The type `ViewModel_*` will not be available in the first round. During this round, the type of the field will be [`ErrorType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/ErrorType.html) (i.e. [`TypeKind.ERROR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/TypeKind.html#ERROR)). An annotation prcessor might handle such type by deferring further processing into the next round, as long as [`RoundEnvironment.processingOver()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/RoundEnvironment.html#processingOver()) is `false`.

Anyway, this doesn't quite explain the error message you are seeing on its own. To make any further claims about the cause of your issue, I would have to see a proper example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its good to know about that, I will consider that writing any new annotation processors in future. It has been almost 6 years and this code is no longer needed since android's ViewModels were introduced so I will just approve it as the correct answer.